# matrix for rotation and translation along it's local axis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I came across a particular situation when I would like to rotate an object at the origin and then translate it along its local axis.(everything here is for 2D). The transformation required is shown as:

[image]

Let us consider the rotation required is <45 deg and the transformation matrix is **R**. Similarly, the translation is **W**  units in +ve X and 0 in Y i.e. W > 0, such that the triangle doesn't leave the grid and the translation matrix is **T**.(These are assumptions just for the sake of illustrations I am about to present)

Now, if I do the transformation RT, the result would be:
[image]

and if I do the transformation TR, the result would be:
[image]

None of which is actually giving the required transformation, but one possible way would be to do the following:

1. Rotate the triangle (**R**)
2. Align the triangle to the Y-axis(**R<sup>-1</sup>**)
3. Translate(**T**)
4. Perform the inverse of 2(**R**)
   The series is thus:  **R.T.R<sup>-1</sup>.R**, which in effect is **R.T** which as shown above, **RT** is not the transformation we want.

**R.T.R<sup>-1</sup>.R** transformation shown below as:
[image]

So, what am I missing here, is there some kind of mistake here? How do we achieve the required composite transformation? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is GLM? The question uses language unfamiliar to a mathematician. What are Wunits for example? And in maths there is no such thing as a translation matrix.

Comment: @Ali, The language of GLM is irrelavant, only matrices and matrix transformation is relevant as mentioned in the question. `W` is a variable, it's purely mathematical. and there is a translation matrix i.e. when you use the fourth column of a 4X4 matrix for translation purposes(I'm not sure I may have to lookup, but I think that's what they call `Affine transformation`(?) )

Comment: @Ali , I've edited the question (could you please remove the downvote, I think it's a good question)

Comment: It's not my downvote. But it's clear we'll have to disagree on whether your question is a good one.

Comment: @Ali , the only thing important in the question is how to arrive at the transformation shown as required, a combination of linear transformations that would do that. (Please Ignore rest of the details if you find it irrelevant)

Comment: In the transformation required, why does T represent the second move? Isn't T a horizontal move?

Comment: There are "affine transformations" and they are probably what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation.  However, they are usually represented by multiplication by a matrix and the addition of a vector: $v \rightarrow Mv + b$.  If you think that it can be done just by multiplying by a matrix then you are using "matrix" differently to most people here.  Maybe try a computer related SE.

Comment: @mathlove , you're correct, I made that big mistake, it should had been moving along the X-axis. But, regardless, RT != TR

Comment: @mathlove , I've corrected the error, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @juztcode thank you for the intersting question, shall you please check mine now ? I have got a problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599061/how-to-calculate-the-transformation-matrix-if-the-coordinate-system-translates-a?noredirect=1#comment7398906_3599061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of orientation preserving (rigid) motions of the plane is isomorphic to the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb C)$ of the form

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$
where $a$ is on the unit circle.

This is a problem in the symmetry chapter of Artin's *Algebra*, first edition.  (The entire chapter is devoted to things of this nature and the first edition is quite cheap...)

If you prefer to work in reals, then convince yourself *that* is isomorphic to

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & b_1\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & b_2\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

and your coordinates for your original 'point' are given by

$\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$
(the bottom coordinate must always be fixed at 1)

**Form of the matrix for your problem**
Evidently you have a translation of length $r$ along the $x_1$ axis (given by standard basis vector $\mathbf e_1\in \mathbb R^3$), then a rotation, so

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & b_1\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & b_2\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x $
$= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) &0\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\big(\mathbf x + r\mathbf e_1\big) $
$=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) &0\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x +  r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) &0\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf e_1$
$=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) &0\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x +  r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)  \\ 
\sin(\theta) \\
 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$= r\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)  \\ 
\sin(\theta) \\
 0
\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) &0\\
 0&0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x$
which satisfies the rules from composition of rotations and translations (2.5) given earlier in the chapter.

*note*: equations can be read forward and backward.  If you start at the bottom and read this backward, it reads as "I... rotate an object at the origin and then translate it."  (as stated in OP.)

conclusion: this tells you that $b_1 = r\cos(\theta)$ and $b_2 = r\sin(\theta)$

Comment: is there a general form of the last line of the equation for 3D coordinate systems?