# How are rotation matrices considered linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations

This may sound like a dumb question, but its been bothering me for a while. We know that trigonometric functions are non linear functions. However, why are rotation matrices (and transformation matrices (such as affine)) considered linear mapping, since they are essentially made up of trigonometric entities. While from a higher level, the rotation matrices do satisfy the constraints that define what a linear mapping is (i.e. it preserves addition and scalar multiplication, additionally the rotation operation is invertible), however, when thinking of a perspective of building up from the individual trigonometric elements, I fail to understand how the non-linearity suddenly becomes a linear mapping, from an intuitive sense.

Note, I do understand that rotation by itself is a linear mapping, but I am more confused about the linearity of the rotation matrix while building up from trigonometric elements. Or, has my understanding been completely wrong and rotation cannot be considered linear mapping?
Thanks

Comment: "*while building up from trigonometric elements*"  Why should the elements of a matrix have anything to do with the linearity of the matrix?  All matrices represent linear transformations...

Comment: Perhaps you are falling into the trap of confusing the concepts of "linear" in the algebraic sense with "line" in the geometric sense... These are unrelated.  Yes, the equation of a line and the equation of a trigonometric function are notably different.  That is irrelevant to the question of linearity from an algebraic sense.

Comment: a rotation matrix corresponds to a linear map on $\mathbb R^2$, say; it may have trigonometric function terms like $\cos\theta$, but it does not map $\theta$

Comment: In a word, remember that when you rotate through angle $\theta$, the angle $\theta$ is *fixed*. So $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are just fixed numbers.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz I have found the answer to my question. Your point of geometric vs algebraic linearity is true and it is something that sometimes confuses me. I do have an understanding of them, but in a few occasions I do tend to mix them. Could you elaborate on why they are difference in an intuitive sense, I would love to hear more of your view that can strengthen my understanding. Thanks!

Comment: a word of caution:  OP wrote "*why are rotation matrices (and **transformation matrices (such as affine)) considered linear mapping***"  -- this isn't true.  Affine transformations are never linear mappings except in the trivial case.  You can model affine transformations using a particular matrix subgroup e.g. see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523274/matrix-for-rotation-and-translation-along-its-local-axis/ for the real 2-d case in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any four numbers $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$, the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\(x,y)&\mapsto&(ax+by,cx+dy)\end{array}$$is linear. And, for every real number $\theta$, the numbers $\cos\theta$ and $\pm\sin\theta$ are real numbers. So, in particular, the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\bigl(\cos(\theta)x-\sin(\theta)y,\sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta)y\bigr)\end{array}$$is linear. And it turns out that thse maps are precisely the rotations of $\Bbb R^2$ and that its matrix with respect to the standard basis is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. The fact that the numbers $\cos\theta$ and $\pm\sin\theta$ were obtained from the trigonometric functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ doesn't change that.

Comment: Ah now I understand. The rotation is a function of my points, and not the other way around.

Comment: I would put it another way: the rotation is a function of the angle: choose you rotation angle $\theta$, and that determines the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To be somewhat explicit about it, a rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear map

from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$, which maps $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ linearly,

even though $\theta\mapsto \cos\theta$ is not a linear map from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$; think of $\theta$ as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ isn't an *actual* rotation in case $\theta$ is a fixed number.

As an example, a window's wing may be rotated by $90^\circ$ to open it. Then the *actual rotation*, i.e., the act of opening it, isn't described by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  Instead you have to imagine to look at the window, then close your eyes while someone opens the window and then open your eyes again to see the result.